# Create a new column in R based off of values for an existing column in my data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, new-operator, calculated-columns

I have a data frame called wine that contains mostly numeric columns that are attributes of wine. One of the columns is the level of Magnesium. I want to create a new factor column in my data frame called high_Magnesium where if the value of Magnesium is 100 or more the value in the new column is "High" and if less than 100 the value in the new column is "Low". I've tried a for loop/if else statement but I'm confident I'm not doing that correctly as I'm not getting the result I need. Any help is appreciated. I'm 4 weeks into my R learning experience and I've mostly enjoyed it.

```
for( i in 1:nrow(wine))(
if(wine$Magnesium[i] >=  "100")(
  wine$high_Magnesium[i] <- "High"
else(wine$Magnesium[i] < "100")(
  wine$high_Magnesium[i] <- "Low"

       
)

)
```

Comment: `wine$high_Magnesium <- ifelse(wine$Magnesium >= 100, "High", "Low")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble(wine) %>% mutate(
  High = case_when(Magnesium >= 100 ~ 1, Magnesium < 100 ~ 0),
  Low = case_when(Magnesium < 100 ~ 1, Magnesium >= 100 ~ 0)
)
```

or

```
as_tibble(wine) %>% mutate(
  High = if_else(Magnesium >= 100, 1, 0)
  Low = if_else(Magnesium < 100, 1, 0)
)
```